# Cross-compiling monogame project for Apple Silicon/universal binary on x64 windows/linux

Tags: .net-core, cross-compiling, monogame

I have read the monogame documentation page for packaging and it seems like it only contains instructions for compiling for osx-x64. However I would like to compile for osx-arm64.
So I ran this command:  `dotnet publish -c Release -r osx-arm64 /p:PublishReadyToRun=false /p:TieredCompilation=false --self-contained` on my windows machine, built an application bundle according to the folder structures and sent it to my friend who owns a M1 Mac. When he ran it his system showed this:[image: The application "TestGame" can't be opened.]

Is this the correct steps to produce a binary for apple silicon? And, is there a way I can compile  a universal binary?